# Is possible install Eclipse IDE in a Galaxy Tab?

Tags: android, eclipse, tablet, android-3.0-honeycomb, galaxy

Since Eclipse can run in Linux and this tablet has the new Honeycomb (Linux Kernel), can Eclipse IDE run in Android Honeycomb ?

I know that isn't pretty much comfortable coding in a tablet, but I'd want to use for UML modeling.

Comment: Waiting in an airport lounge turning pleasant at last ;-) !!!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Android (despite its Linux roots) is far from capable of running Eclipse IDE as is. Not only is the hardware inadequate for supporting such a large application, but Android lacks a full Java SE JVM (Dalvik is a subset) and SWT (Eclipse UI framework) implementation for native Android UI controls does not exist. On Linux, SWT implementations exist only for GTK and Motif.

You may be interested in project Orion, which is an effort at eclipse.org to create Eclipse-like experience in the browser. I understand that people have been able to use Orion from a mobile browser on devices such as the one on the iPad.

http://mmilinkov.wordpress.com/2011/01/11/introducing-orion/

Comment: IMO, Android's Linux roots is irrelevent -- what's interesting is its Java roots; that's what makes one fantasize that Eclipse might conceivably run on it.

Comment: @KirkWoll not quite imho: it's linux roots enable android devices to run a (more) full fledged GNU/Linux, where Eclipse is able to run. (In fact that's what I'm doing- despite the lack of a proper Xserver for Android [supporting GL] that is not painfully slow, just sluggish)

Answer (score 16):

**No you can't.**

But who forbid you to connect to your computer using VNC? You can access your Eclipse or whatever application you want.

Answer (score 7):

You can't run Eclipse but you can try AIDE:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.aide.ui

It is compatible with the Eclipse project file format, has a fast editor with syntax highlighting and supports the full edit-compile-run cycle.

Answer (score 3):

1.) The latest Android tablets ARE now powerful enough to run software like the Eclipse IDE in fact they are more powerful than the Intel and AMD processor machines that Eclipse was originally developed to run on.

2.) The tablet is a useful tool for graphical modelling techniques and the addition of an external wireless keyboard can improve input of code in a text editor.

3.) There is a lack of support for Java SE runtime for Android.

4.) Limited Android root access on the standard commercially supplied Tablets make it impossible to access OS features and install, compile or access development tools without additional 3rd party applications.

5.) AIDE does provide a method to write and run code on Android but the free version is extremely limited and the commercial (paid) version is nowhere near as powerful or comprehensive as the freely available Eclipse for Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can use DroidDevelop.
DroidDevelop allows to create native Android application on your mobile device. You don't need to install Android SDK, Eclipce and an other desktop program for Windows or Linux to start programing for Android.

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.assoft.DroidDevelop

http://en.assoft.ru/droiddevelop

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, no.

Long answer, although Honeycomb is based on Linux, you'd have to do a lot of hacking to get to the point where you can have a full blown IDE installed on it. Android works with apps. There isn't an Eclipse app, so you can't have Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

There was actually a version of [Ubuntu for Android](http://www.ubuntu.com/phone/ubuntu-for-android), you could do the Ubuntu install for Eclipse on your tablet if you were running it.

As for running Eclipse on an android OS? Not so much since Android has no real JVM.

Answer (score 0):

The [Eclipse downloads page](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) lists packages for Windows, Linux, and Mac OSX.
Android is not listed as one of the supported OSes for installation of the IDE.

Comment: ok But these are the packages ready to download, since Eclipse IDE is an open source project, source are available to download. Is posible compile it into Honeycomb?

Comment: Here is a link to a HOWTO that explains how to get the Eclipse source code: http://wiki.eclipse.org/CVS_Howto
I haven't heard of anyone porting the source to Android, but feel free to do so if you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about actually running Java code with Eclipse APIs on the device?  It's not impossible, but you will be doing most of the work yourself. The difficult part will be getting SWT to run and appear as native Android objects while supporting the full range of controls that Eclipse users expect.

There have been Eclipse projects in the past to get a workable subset of the APIs to run in an embedded space. One such project was eRCP, by IBM. I'm not aware of any activity to make a similar effort on Android, but there's no requirement to announce such work to the Eclipse community.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to install Eclipse directly to Android OS but you can run Eclipse on your Tablet via Linux Deploy Application. But first you need to get Linux setup on your Android and use VNC viewer for display. That's how I did it.

See screen shot of Linux on Android running [Eclipse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGlu8.png).