# Wanted: offline IDE for developing Html / JavaScript on Android tablet

Tags: javascript, android, css, ide, android-3.0-honeycomb

In have a Motorola Xoom tablet and I would like to use it to develop some small Html / Css / JavaScript / jQuery applications. **Does anyone know a good IDE to do web development on Android?

I only need the IDE for: *html, css, jQuery / JavaScript* (other languages would be cool though).

**Clarification**: *The development takes place **on** the tablet, so the IDE must run **on** the tablet.*
 <sub>I would like to do some JSFiddle-like stuff when I'm travelling by train, that's why I need a **offline** editor.</sub>

Comment: Maybe you should be extremely specific when you asking such a special question... as you see in the answers, it wasn't clear what you want...

Comment: See related question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715697/what-is-the-best-ide-to-develop-android-apps-in

Comment: @Ace, it's about development **on** the Tablet. The related question is about development **for** the Tablet.

Comment: I see, I'm not sure if there is. This will also benefit me as I'm getting an android phone soon. Anyway check this link https://market.android.com/details?id=com.welant.webmaster and http://mashable.com/2010/03/10/android-apps-web-developer/ sorry if this can't be a help.

Comment: I don't have a constructive answer for you, but why would you want to develop on a tablet? If you want to program on the move, isn't it better to have a small laptop with you, where you can run all browsers for testing and any editors/IDEs you want(not to mention the luxury of a complete keyboard rather than those compact designs)? While tablets are very helpful for doing stuff on the move, I don't think we're at the point where programming on one is comfortable. Just a suggestion.

Comment: @Mumim, I love to do some experimenting with jQuery while I'm on a plane. Laptops and planes don't mix that well. 'Complete keyboard' can be a matter of proper software.

Comment: I've updated to 3.2, maybe there is better XHTML5 offline support

Comment: I think we should reopen the question until we have an answer :)

Comment: Android Web Developer - will be great for your needs. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kidinov.awd . Iam developer of this app.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could use the [online IDE](http://cloud9ide.com/). It's the Mozilla project that started out as Bespin a few years ago.

I've been playing with it for a while, and I am quite impressed with how well it works. And it hooks right into github.

There are even ways of [running it in offline mode](http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2011/05/working-offline-with-cloud9-on-google.html).

Comment: My Xoom wil arrive tomorrow, so I'm going to test your solution :-).

Comment: did you try it out? I'm getting my xoom in a couple of days too... ;-)

Comment: mmm... it looks the best alternative instead installing huge development packages on a mobile device. Very interesting!

Comment: Offline doesn't work for me on my Xoom (3.1)

Answer (score 3):

Try WebBaster's HTML Editor from [Android Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.welant.webmaster) (Pro version)
The IDE has syntax highlighting, code-completion and quick preview

Lite version is [also available](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.welant.webmaster.DEMO) in Android Market

Answer (score 2):

maybe an online editor like [ACE](http://ace.ajax.org/) (former Mozilla bespin/skywriter)?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I would go with [vim](http://code.google.com/p/android-cruft/downloads/detail?name=vim-7.3-android-binary.tar.gz&can=2&q=) (dont forget to [read the blog post](http://credentiality2.blogspot.com/2010/08/native-vim-for-android.html) about this Android version and this [little tutorial](http://gdr.geekhood.net/gdrwpl/vim-android.php) with another solution) with [zencoding](http://code.google.com/p/zen-coding/) plugin. But I'm a little biased since I use vim daily for development and I'm already used to it's modal approach.

It's a good opportunity to learn a new editor nonetheless, and understand why the hell [these nutheads use vi](http://www.viemu.com/a-why-vi-vim.html).

There's a [good post about vim](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/09/coming-home-to-vim/) as well, with some plugins for web development. Beware though that a lot may not work in your Android environment.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. You should try some text editors:

- TextWarrior
- JecEditor
- Jota Edit
- Touchqode
- Silver Edit
- etc.

The first 2 support multiple charsets and syntax highlighting. You can use andFTP as client if you work on remote servers. On LAN you can also flash a custom kernel to your device with cifs support, or load the cifs.ko module if you have root access, and mount the shared folder on the local filesystem (like mapping a network drive) for easier access to the files.

Another idea is to load Ubuntu on your device via chroot method, and use it connecting vnc to localhost, then you can use the arm ports of your favorite software, like geany, firefox, etc. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

You can looks for [Android Scripting](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/).

I wrote simple JS solutions on it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this post can give you some path to an answer: [Is possible install Eclipse IDE in a Galaxy Tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079986/is-possible-install-eclipse-ide-in-a-galaxy-tab)

It looks the JVM is not ported yet on such platform.

Remember the Java technology is portable to any system as long a JVM exists for that platform (OS + CPU type).

But honestly, even with a full portability of the Eclipse IDE, I doubt the performance would be enough to be usable in the real programming task on the actual tablets (e.g. The samsung Galaxy Tab have a 1Ghz processor only... )

Comment: Well... Eclipse might be a little bit much to develop only HTML / JavaScript :-)

Comment: Yes perhaps in that case a text editor with syntax highlighting will be sufficient. I would suggset firefox and firebug for debugging, but I do not now if that very useful add-in is working on a mobile device.

Comment: So we are ruling out Eclipse because a Java environment is lacking.

Answer (score 0):

The Eclipse foundation started a project, too. It's called [Orion](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Orion) and currently in Open Beta. It's ment to develope JavaScript and HTML and it has a build-in git repo.

Comment: Click on the link and find out.