# Web programming on iOS or Android, is it possible?

Tags: android, ios, ide, development-environment

I'm looking for a mobile device to program on, since netbooks are usually very slow (even with linux..) is there any good alternative to program on ipad or android tablets? (PHP and Javascript)

It seems my question was misunderstood: I want to program **ON** an iPad or Android tablet, not **FOR** them.

Comment: Do you want to code on your mobile device and search for an online IDE? If so, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5934518/wanted-offline-ide-for-developing-html-javascript-on-android-tablet/6057086#comment-7368459). If not, see the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at Appcelerator Titanium. With Titanium Studio you can develop apps for iOS, Android and Blackberry using JavaScript. You can code cross-platform with it.

The learning curve is much less steep than learning ObjectiveC and Java. But you have to install the SDK you are interested in - in the case of Android and Blackberry this might be some work. Also, for developing on iOS, you need a Mac.