# Run IDE, for Java, ON Android 3.1

Tags: compiler-construction, ide, java, android-3.1-honeycomb

I am about to purchase a tablet probably a Thrive. I need to know if I can write applications in Java, to use on a regular PC, on a tablet using Android 3.1. I am in school and I write a lot of applications using Java. I need to be able to write code using a tablet running Android 3.1 Honeycomb.

Also if I can do this what IDE can I use?

NOTE: I am not trying to write Android applications in Java. I am trying to write applications in Java (for regular PC) using a IDE from a tablet with Android 3.1 honeycomb.

Basically I want to:

- Install Java JDK on Toshiba Thrive
- Install IDE on Toshiba Thrive (such as eclipse, jgrasp, netbeans)
- Run IDE and write code in Java
- Save code to flashdrive
- Use/edit code on my PC

Comment: In other words, you want to use your tablet as a Java development system?

Comment: I don't think there is a Java JDK that runs on Android. If you really want to code on the tablet, maybe some Remote Desktop or web-based IDE would work.

Comment: You can use JRuby, though, so at least you could play with the JDK.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079986/is-possible-install-eclipse-ide-in-a-galaxy-tab

Comment: Also, there would be no Swing or AWT or SWT, so developing PC GUI apps seems quite impossible.

Comment: Ted Hopp - Yes that is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I guess since this is not possible, then can I install Ubuntu on a tablet. Then use Ubuntu tablet as my Java development system?

Comment: I'm looking for this too. My workaround so far is to chroot into an arm debian on my android.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Google Play and download AIDE although it is for designing Android Apps on cell phone.
It works on my android tablet and takes Java. With a few tweaks I bet you could make it compile and run pure java. Please cheak it out and let me know. I am working on it right now.
I need portable java development on the go anywhere!!

Comment: That is very cool, although just the thought of developing with an onscreen keyboard makes my wrists hurt

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that on a normal Android tablet, the best you can hope is to use Remote Desktop/TeamViewer/VNC to remotely use a normal PC an do your actual development there. One option you have is to root the tablet and install Ubuntu side-by-side the Android environment, but I'm doubtful that the OpenJDK will be up to the task.

On the third hand, a tablet is a device that is very hostile to text entry, and you wnt to perform an activity that is very text-heavy. Are you on the right track? (not to menttion the question on how to perforn shift-ctrl-f on a tablet)

Answer (score 1):

With the latest Asus tablet that runs Android on a quad-core chip, I see this as a possibility in the near future if not now.  Essentially, it would be like a merge of iPad and MacBook.

And no AWT/SWing/etc is not a problem for me, since I will be doing server-side development (using Eclipse/tomcat).

Now the question:
How hard is it to port JDK onto Android?

Allen S.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DroidDevelop

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.assoft.DroidDevelop

http://en.assoft.ru/droiddevelop