# Android development on tablet: Will Eclipse run on windows tablet?

Tags: android, windows, tablet

Will Eclipse and android SDK run on windows tablet?or is there any other device as portable as a tablet that it can run on(like sony vaio p and sony vaio ux)?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079986/is-possible-install-eclipse-ide-in-a-galaxy-tab

Comment: Are you asking about an existing piece of hardware? Or the WinRT surface tablet?

Comment: If it runs the real Windows and the thing has an x86 processor then yes. I doubt it will run on WindowsRT

Comment: The question in the link is about galaxy tab.I want to know if it will work on windows tab

Comment: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**AIDE**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=en) lets you develop for Android, on Android. It runs well on most Android Tablets.

Eclipse **wont** run on Windows RT till it is ported, but **Windows 8** on Tablets can run eclipse (and anything that runs on Windows 7) easily.
So you could either go the Android way, or wait for the Surface running Windows 8.

Answer (score 1):

Yes but it depends on the tablet...
 Key Features

```
Toshiba WT200 Windows Tablet
10.1" LED-backlit capactive multi-touch display 
1366 x 768 Screen resolution
 Intel Atom N2600 1.6GHz processor
2GB DDR3 Memory
64GB Solid State Drive
3G and WiFi connectivity 
Windows 7 Professional 32bit
```

Answer (score 1):

Windows RT will only be able to run apps available via the Windows Store, the question is will the Eclipse team create a version for it?

**From Wikipedia**

*Only software written using the Windows Runtime (Metro style apps) can be used on Windows RT with the exception of Microsoft Office 2013 and the desktop version of Internet Explorer 10. Developers will not be able to create applications to run on Windows RT using the Win32 APIs*

Windows 8 Pro which runs on the Intel based CPU architecture (Ivy-Bridge) should run Eclipse and be fully backward compatible with other Windows apps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the new Intel-based tablets (window 8) will run eclipse or I would get an UltraBook!